# Kendo MaskedTextBox data attributes

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-maskedtextbox

Can MaskedTextBox be configured via data attributes?

I tried the following but did not work.

```
<input data-role='kendo.ui.MaskedTextBox' data-mask='(999) 000-0000' />
```

Thanks.

Comment: This has been introduced in the latest release. Are you using it?

Comment: thanks for mentioning this, I was using the older version. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can; are you sure you're instructing Kendo UI to initialize the DOM elements (either by calling `kendo.init` or by binding a view model)? Both of these work:

```
<div id="example">
    <input data-role="maskedtextbox" data-mask="(999) 000-0000" />
    <input data-role="kendo.ui.MaskedTextBox" data-mask="(999) 000-0000" />
</div>

$(function() {
    kendo.init($("#example"));
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/6JAwM/))